# How to retrieve all documents where two fields' value are equals with pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection and I want to extract all the documents where some date field is smaller than an other date field, using python.

I know how to do it in `robomongo`:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').find({'date1' : {'$lt' : ISODate(this.date2)}})
```

But this doesn't work when I use `pymongo`. I tried using `datetime` instead of ISODate but had no luck.

Edit: both date1 and date2 are fields' names

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: what is `this.date2`? is `date2` field's name?

Comment: yes, it is field's name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`.aggregate()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) method which provides access to the aggregation pipeline and the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator.

```
pipeline = [
    {'$match': {'date1': {'$exists': True}, 'date2': {'$exists': True}}},
    {'$redact': {'$cond': [{'$lt': ['$date1', '$date2']}, '$$KEEP', '$$PRUNE']}}
]
collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

The `$redact` will return all documents match the condition using [`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep) and discards those that don't match using the [`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune) variable.

The [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage is optional but good to have. All it does is a preliminary filtering which limits the amount of documents that will be processed in the next stage. Also `$redact` does a collection scan so having `$match` will just make things better.

Answer (score 2):

From the [API pages](https://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0/tutorial.html#range-queries), you can use

```
d = datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 12, 12)
collection.find({"date": {"$lt": d}})
```

Comment: Thanks David, my problem is that date2 is also a field in my document, I can't define it.